# Disabling bot in the specific servers

Tags: javascript, node.js, if-statement, discord.js

I want to disable my bot in specific server(s) and I want to put it in my command if statements. How to do it?

```js
if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) /* || Disabling the specific servers here */) return;
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Check the guild ID

```js
if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || ["guildId1", "guildId2"].includes(message.guildId)) return;
```